# TypeError: web3.eth.Contract is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, solidity, web3js

Please how so I solve these error with web3.js
[Snapshot of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXRju.png)

```
const web3Token = new web3.eth.Contract(ERC20Token.abi);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are probably using a version of web3 < 1.0.

Try this:

```
const web3Token = web3.eth.contract(ERC20Token.abi);
```

source: https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/3139